# How to host wordpress on a url path instead of subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

Hi we have a blog hosted on our website at: https://blog.mergequeue.com where the main application is hosted on a separate box using nginx https://mergequeue.com

We want the blog to instead be rendered from mergequeue.com/blog but that doesn't seem to work when I setup the configuration on Wordpress and Nginx side. The Wordpress is running on a separate server using a standard buster docker image that has apache + php running. Has anyone tried this before and what configuration to use on nginx and Wordpress side to make this work? Here's the nginx config I tried:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    {{ domain_name }};
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/www/static;
    }
    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://<wordpress_public_ip>:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried proxy_pass http://<wordpress_public_ip>:5000/ (with slash on the end) ?

Comment: Yes that just adds an additional slash for Wordpress side, but doesn't work. I get recursive loop error on Apache / WP side

Comment: I think Your solution is in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135042/wordpress-on-docker-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-using-ssl
but that without testing personally I think that You need something like this:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/blog".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
in wp-config.php