# 502 Bad Gateway - SSL handshake error: wrong version number

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl

I'm trying to set up SSL for my wordpress site and while the certificate is valid and working I get a bad gateway error.
I'm not sure if this has to due to something I need to change in some wordpress file, or due to my nginx file that I only half understand and cobbled up together.

**Nginx config**:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  include snippets/well-known;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  if ($host != "example.com") {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  include snippets/well-known;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}

# ----- Below is config for my mailcow server, same ip, running on mail.example.com -------
# 95% sure there's no issues here, since it seems to work perfectly
# taken from https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/firststeps-rp/

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name mail.example.com autodiscover.* autoconfig.* xmpp_prefix_if_any.domain *.xmpp_prefix_if_any.domain;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mail.example.com autodiscover.* autoconfig.* xmpp_prefix_if_any.domain *.xmpp_prefix_if_any.domain;

  ssl_certificate /opt/mailcow-dockerized/data/assets/ssl/mail.example.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/mailcow-dockerized/data/assets/ssl/mail.example.com/key.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!SHA1:!kRSA;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75;
    proxy_send_timeout 3650;
    proxy_read_timeout 3650;
    proxy_buffers 64 256k;
    client_body_buffer_size 512k;
    client_max_body_size 0;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    client_max_body_size 0;
  }
}
```

**Error** from `sudo tail -1 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2021/05/30 16:17:35 [error] 535009#535009: *10 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 94.102.200.197, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

I made sure to change the wordpress siteurl and homeurl to be http**s**://example.com as per some threads online that said that was the issue, but nothing changed.
If I change the proxy_pass location from `proxy_pass https://localhost:3000` to be http, the website sorta loads (no gateway error), but almost no css or images load. /wp-login is still unavailable though. I think this maybe gives a hint at a solution but I'm at a loss of what to try now.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: *"If I change the proxy_pass location from proxy_pass https://localhost:3000 to be http, the website sorta loads (no gateway error),..."* - that's the answer to your question. Since on port 3000 only HTTP is used you must use `http://` in the `proxy_pass` directive and not `https://`.  *"... but almost no css or images load. ..."* - that's a different problem and completely unrelated to your main problem in the question. Please ask a new question for this with enough detail. Specifically use developer tools in the browser to see which URL's it is trying to access and likely they are wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks a lot, seems like I've spent all evening trying to fix the wrong thing. It just didn't make sense to me to pass in http when I wanted https, still don't quite understand, but now that I searched for the problem to fix the css and images loading I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135042/wordpress-on-docker-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-using-ssl which did it.  What's the proper thing to do now, should I delete the question or leave it up just in case someone may need?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the other question. This makes this question than a duplicate.